# How to upload file to the web server from a known path in the system without browsing it using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to dvelop a web application to upload any image file to the web server without browsing it.Knowing the path where the image is stored in the system,directly click upload button to upload it to the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security reasons this is impossible without using a flash or java component.
And even then the security will be tight.
You are basicly asking for a way to pull a file from a clients computer when he clicks a button.
The next step is just pulling a file without him actually doing anything at all(you see where i'm going with this?)
You have to use the browse button so your browser knows for sure that a user selected a file from his computer and that user choose to upload it to your web application.
 Deciding which file to retreive after the user clicked the button(even if you know the exact path to his save games/passwords file/ financial data / outlook mail location) is not possible for verry valid reasons.

Comment: Hello Kristof.....Is there any other way,actually i have developed a web application.In that web application i executing a exe file which is installed in the system.it is possible only in IE using ActiveX object.The application is to scan image.Once the image is scanned it is saved in the local system.i want to save it in the server instead

Comment: Hey Chandan, if you manage to get a piece of software installed on the client then everything is possible security wise. Active X however does not work on firefox or chrome so you would have to resort to flash or a java applet. I'm sure it's doable but i'm affraid i can't provide much help for either of these as i lack the experience. I'm fairly certain however that you'll have to custom make it so get ready to dive into flash/java ! :D